# Dynamic form handling in react

Tags: reactjs

I am developing a form with dynamic html elements. I want to submit form but the html elements name are not predefined. All the fields(HTML controls are fetched from an API.

I am able to get the fields name and fields initial value using axios. Number of fields and name of fields are all dynamic. I have also done the changehandler function as below

```
  onChangeHandler = event => {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });
  };
```

Below is the state definition

```
  state = {
    datajson: [],
    fieldname: []
  };
```

where datajson contain all the data and field values. fieldname contains fields name.

I want to submit form and get the data in a json object (below is the sample json object), which can then be sent using axios to database for updating record.

```
postSubmit=()=>{
fieldname1:this.state.fieldvalue,
fieldname2:this.state.fieldvalue1
fieldname2:this.state.fieldvalue2
}
```

I have defined all the above code in class component.
How to achieve the form submission for above scenario??

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Sorry I have edited the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save form values in an object in state and submit it on form post.

```
onChangeHandler = event => {
  const { fields } = this.state;
  fields[name] = event.target.value;
  this.setState({
    fields,
  });
};
```

State would look like this:

```
state = {
  datajson: [],
  fieldname: [],
  fields: {},
};
```

And your submit function:

```
postSubmit=()=>{
  // post fields to api.
  const { fields } = this.state;
}
```

Are you looking for something like this?

Comment: I have tried your code but it give me error of unexpected use of fields[name] in onChangeHandler event. .

Comment: Thanks gergana. I have just changed a line and my code is working as expected. Thanks a lot. fields[event.target.name] is what I had changed. or if I had misunderstood your code then its all correct.